# How to force cmake not to find mpicxx but only mpicc

Tags: makefile, cmake, mpi, build-tools

I am trying to use cmake to generate Makefile for a MPI program. The issue I have is that I only have mpicc installed (working correctly) the mpicxx is in the PATH but is from an other installation (there are multiple MPIs installed on my system). I don't want to use mpicxx but only mpicc (and the include files and libraries of mpicc).

Bellow is a somewhat hardcoded effort and it works

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

    PROJECT(mympihello)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(hellompi hellompi.c)
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
    target_link_libraries(hellompi /export/home2/SEECS/bibrak/work/programs/installs/mpich3/include)
```

Following is the generic way (as far as I know) and I want to use this approach but forcing not to use mpicxx (not finding it, discarding mpicxx)

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

    PROJECT(mympihello)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(hellompi hellompi.c)

  # Require MPI for this project:
    find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_LINK_FLAGS})
    include_directories(MPI_INCLUDE_PATH)
    target_link_libraries(hellompi ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

Furthermore, it will be helpful to point me towards how to generate .so (shared library) for such programs that use MPI.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some how I managed to do it. Here is my solution to generating .so (shared library) using cmake but only using mpicc not mpicxx

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

    project(projectname C)

    SET(    SOURCE_FILES
            sourcefile1.c
            sourcefile2.c
            sourcefile3.c
    )

    ADD_LIBRARY(projectname SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
    find_package(MPI)
    if(MPI_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_C_COMPILE_FLAGS})
    set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_C_LINK_FLAGS})

    include_directories(${MPI_C_INCLUDE_PATH})
    endif(MPI_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(projectname ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES})
```

This generates a Makefile that creates projectname.so shared library.